# ESXi plugin check_esx3-0.5 for Nagios shows error on Webfront

Tags: vmware-esxi, nagios

Could someone provide me with solution for the following problem:

I have ESXi 4.0 enterprise edition (old one, but that can not be changed). 
I want to monitor ESXi from Nagios server. And I use check_esx3-0.5.pl plugin http://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=2154&cf_id=29 from Nagios exchabge page.

That plugin for monitoring ESXi on Nagios server does work when type command from Nagios server. Here is what I have:

```
  ./check_esx3-0.5.pl -H 172.32.3.3 -u user -p password -l vmfs
```

And result is:

```
{CHECK_ESX3-0.5.PL OK - Storages : iSCSI ibm storage=219492.00 MB (23.02%)
, datastore esxi04=60704.00 MB (93.36%), Storage Backup=853604.69 MB (60.13%)
 | 'iSCSI ibm storage'=219492.00MB;; 'datastore esxi04'=60704.00MB;; '
 Storage Backup'=853604.69MB;;}
```

Above is completely correct answer.

Here are my settings - commands definitions:

```
define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template   
to use
    host_name                       esxi03.troxo.net
    service_description             PING
    check_command                   check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
contact_groups              admins        
}


VMWare check cpu
define service{
    use                             local-service
    host_name                       esxi03.troxo.net
    service_description             ESXi CPU Load
    check_command                   check_esx_cpu!80!90
    }

Define a service to check the Memory Usage on the remote machine. 
Warning if > 80%, critical if > 90%.

check memory usage
define service{
    use                             local-service
    host_name                       esxi03.troxo.net
    service_description             ESXi Memory usage
    check_command                   check_esx_mem!80!90
    }

Define a service to check RunTime Status on the remote machine. 

check runtime status
define service{
    use                             local-service
    host_name                       esxi03.troxo.net
    service_description             ESXi Runtime status
    check_command                   check_esx_runtime
    }

 check io read
 define service{
    use                             local-service
    host_name                       esxi03.troxo.net
    service_description             ESXi IO read
    check_command                   check_esx_ioread!40!90
    }

  check io write
  define service{
    use                             local-service
    host_name                       esxi03.troxo.net
    service_description             ESXi IO write
    check_command                   check_esx_iowrite!40!90
    }

  Define a service to check vmfs free space on the remote machine.

  check io write
  define service{
    use                             local-service
    host_name                       esxi03.troxo.net
    service_description             ESXi VMFS Free Space
    check_command                   check_vmfs
    }
  }
```

I added to resources.cfg user & pass for login to ESXi. commands.cfg file looks like:

```
check io write
      define command{
       command_name check_esx_iowrite
       command_line $USER1$/check_esx3-0.5.pl -D $HOSTADDRESS$ -u $USER3$ -p $USER4$ 
         -l io -s write -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
        }

check vmfs
   define command{
    command_name check_vmfs
     command_line $USER1$/check_esx3-0.5.pl -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u $USER3$ -p $USER4$ -l vmfs
       -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
    }
```

Only ping command is OK. Others are declared as Unknown. Here is what do I have on Nagios page:

```
    ESXi VMFS Free Space

UNKNOWN 03-08-2012 13:56:34  ..... Usage: check_esx.pl -D <data_center>
```

user3 & user4 are login & pass for ESXi on resources.cfg
I do not have Center Server installed - not necessary for 6 ESXi servers.
So, could someone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command definition is expecting ARG1 and ARG2 (for -w and -c, respectively), but you are not passing them in after check_vmfs in your service def's command line.

So the resulting command being executed by Nagios is something like "/path/to/check_esx3-0.5.pl -H 172.32.3.3 -u user -p passwd -l vmfs -w -c", which is why it's returning "error: here's the usage help" instead of what you expect.

You should either remove the -w and -c pieces from the command definition, or add some (I'm assuming) thresholds to your service definition. E.g., "check_vmfs!10!20" or similar.

Comment: Thank you Keith. Sorry for late answer. I will test it and give a reply